# Hive: Generate date by passing month, weekday and occurrence

Tags: hive, timestamp

I am looking for options to *derive a datetime value* from a table where data is present in below format

```
col1(year) - 2007
col2(month) - 03
col3(day) - 1 [ 1 (sunday) , 2 (monday) and so on]
col4(occurence) - 2 (2nd week or last week)
```

This table needs to be used as - get date for sunday from 2nd week of Mar 2007.

Is there a way I can use these columns and derive a date as 11th Mar 2007 in Hive?

Comment: Just concatenate the columns (cast as string and left pad with zeros if necessary): `col1 || '-' || col2 || '-' || col3 AS date_col`

Comment: @foglerit this wont get me the actual day 11th Mar. It will just get a result as 2007-03-01.

Comment: Once you have the date in a format Hive can understand, you can format it however you want with `date_format()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@shah; I assumed that col1, col2, col3 and col4 are integers and the logic is to get the last day of the previous month then add x number of weeks then get the next day from that date. Here is the sample code:

```
Sample: 2008 02  1 3  (third sunday of feb 2018) 

Query: select next_day(date_add(last_day(concat_ws('-',cast(2018 as string),cast(2-1 as string),cast(1 as string))), 7*(3-1)) ,if(1=1,'SUN',if(1=2,'MON', if(1=3,'TUE',if(1=4,'WED',if(1=5,'THU',if(1=6,'FRI',if(1=7,'SAT','SUN'))))))));

Result: 2018-02-18  

Steps: Change 2018 into col1, change cast(2-1 as string) into cast(col2-1 as string), change 7*(3-1) into 7*(col4-1) and change if(1=1, into if(col3=1,
```

Functions that I used are next_day, date_add, last_day and concat_ws. You may find their usage on this link. https://www.qubole.com/resources/hive-function-cheat-sheet/

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @anonyXmous.. worked well except below scenario. Lets say i pass 2008 03 1 5 (5th sunday of mar) - above query will get me 1st apr. As march does not have 5th sunday, it should return last sunday 25th Mar. Sorry i did not include this condition earlier. I would be great if you can help me. Thank you

Comment: @shah, So it needs two steps:  1) run the query and put the result in col5 2) you need to validate col4 first and check if the the resulting month of col5 is not the same with col2, then col4 is not correct or over the maximum allowed value. Hope it helps.

Comment: @ anaonyXmous - Thank you. i added a check if month not equal then do date - 7 days else use the same date. Working as expected

Comment: @shah; glad to help!